# Chakra Editable component does not submit when input blurs

Tags: reactjs, forms, chakra-ui

I'm trying to make the data that shows in this card editable, using Chakra's Editable component. According to the docs I should be able to pass the onSubmit prop my handleSubmit function and from there I want to PATCH the edit to my RoR back end. My issue seems to be that the submit never actually happens - again according to the docs either pressing enter or blurring the input will invoke onSubmit, but despite placing console.logs all over my submit function I don't get anything logged to the console, no errors even. I'm at a loss, any help is appreciated.

```
function DadDetails() {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(user.email);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log(user);
    fetch(`/people/${user.id}`, {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email: email }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setUser({ ...user, email: email });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <Card borderRadius="30px">
      <CardHeader>
        <Avatar />
        <Flex flexDir={"column"} ml={4} mt={1}>
          <Heading fontSize="xl">{user.name}</Heading>
        </Flex>
      </CardHeader>

      <CardBody>
        <Stack divider={<StackDivider />} spacing="4">
          <Box>
            <Heading size="xs" textTransform="uppercase">
              Email
            </Heading>
            <Editable
              submitOnBlur={true}
              defaultValue={user.email}
              onSubmit={handleSubmit}
              onChange={(e)=> setEmail(e.target.value)}
            >
              <EditablePreview />
              <EditableInput />
            </Editable>
          </Box>
          <Box>
            <Heading size="xs" textTransform="uppercase">
              Birthday
            </Heading>
            <Text pt="2" fontSize="sm">
              {user.date_of_birth}
            </Text>
          </Box>
          <Box>
            <Heading size="xs" textTransform="uppercase">
              Zip Code
            </Heading>
            <Text pt="2" fontSize="sm">
              {user.zip_code}
            </Text>
          </Box>
        </Stack>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default DadDetails;
```

I tried adding the submitOnBlur prop, also tried setting state and calling submit with the same handler. Tried calling {handleSubmit()} and {()=> handleSubmit()} in the onSubmit prop just cause.  Nothing happens unless it breaks the component render, but nothing seems to actually trigger the submit.

Comment: Your code seems good, but did you check you're setting up state of email on onChange method? Did you get the values inside that email state?

Comment: Not sure how honestly, but I just decided to finish fleshing out the form and it started working after adding the rest of the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

ChakraUI's `Editable` return the value in the `onChange`. You're trying to access a `target` which is not present since the value is a **string**. And you might want to add a `value` prop to have a controlled input.

```js
<Editable
  submitOnBlur={true}
  defaultValue={user.email}
  value={email}
  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
  onChange={(newValue) => setEmail(newValue)}
>
```